# Can I create a loop which fills 100 arrays with six random numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I know how to create a loop which fills only one array with random numbers. But can i create a loop which fills random number of arrays with random numbers. Is it possible in C++ and is it hard to do ? (Thank you for the answer, got a bit of research on vectors and figured it out.

I have one more question. I have a program with a menu from 1 to 4. On the 1. spot is creating a ticket with 6 random numbers and saving them to an array. Is it possible to create a loop with that, which on every click creates a new array with the new values and the other are remained the same. To clarify: I have an array[5]={1,2,3,4,5}. I want when i click on 1, this array to be saved, and to be created a new one, which will hold up the new values and so on. Also if they could be with following up names like array1, array2 and so on. I'm permitted to use only rand() function.

This is my code for now!

```
srand(time(NULL));

for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {
    lottoArr[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
    cout << lottoArr[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible in C++. No, it's not hard.

Comment: In your title you ask about 100 arrays but in the post you mention a random number of arrays. Which one is it?

Comment: Are you trying to fill a random number of arrays out of a total of 100?

Comment: So yeah, my exact question was for 100 hundred arrays, but i asked for random number. It doesn't matter on which you will answer me, because i think it will change on only one place.

Comment: Don't edit question to add another question.

Comment: I know it was a problem. But i couldn't ask a new question :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a random number of arrays you have to store them in a resizable container like a vector, containing the arrays with the six elements. Resize this vector with this random number and then iterate through it and add random numbers

```
#include <array>
#include <random>

namespace
{
  constexpr auto NumberOfArrayElements = 6;
  constexpr auto MaximumNumberOfArrays = 100;

  template<class VectorT>
  void resize_randomly(VectorT& vector)
  {
    std::random_device random_device;
    std::mt19937 engine(random_device());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<VectorT::size_type> 
      distribution(0, MaximumNumberOfArrays > vector.max_size() ? vector.max_size() : MaximumNumberOfArrays);

    vector.resize(distribution(engine));
  }

  void fill_randomly(std::vector<std::array<int, NumberOfArrayElements>>& vector_of_arrays)
  {
    std::random_device random_device;
    std::mt19937 engine(random_device());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest(), std::numeric_limits<int>::max());

    for (auto& array : vector_of_arrays)
      std::generate(array.begin(), array.end(), [&distribution, &engine]() { return distribution(engine); });
  }
}

auto main() -> int 
{
  std::vector<std::array<int, NumberOfArrayElements>> vector_of_arrays;
  resize_randomly(vector_of_arrays);
  fill_randomly(vector_of_arrays);
}
```

Use the C++11 [random](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) feature to generate random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

here it's the way to do it for three array (I fill them with random number between 0 and 100)

```
int tab1[10];
int tab2[10];
int tab3[10];

for( int i = 0; i <6; i++ ) {
    tab1[i]=rand() % 100; 
    tab2[i]=rand() % 100; 
    tab3[i]=rand() % 100; 
}
```

Now you have to adapt this for your case, you can for example make a function who take an array and fill it with random number and call it on the array you want to fill